# How can I set the vscode extension custom icon in activity bar to the first?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I added one icon to the activity bar, and it works well.
I need to put it at the top of the activity bar (at the top for **Resource Management**), how can I reach the requirement?

Now the code like this: Is there any option can change the order?

```json
"viewsContainers": {
  "activitybar": [
    {
      "id": "thingio_sidebar",
      "title": "ThingIO Options",
      "icon": "media/dep.svg"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: If your users really need that, they can drag it to the top themselves. Some user like me never likes an extension to make the decision.

Comment: If intellisense doesn't show another option it probably doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But the PM gave me the requirement like this. Maybe I need a further UI discussion with him.